# SnagIt vs Screenpresso, Which to get Based on specific features found in SnagIt, but not trial version of Screenpresso?

Tags: manual-testing, tools, functional, exploratory

I am a tester for uTest.com who uses screenshots and screen capture extensively for my test cycles. I used the free trial versions of both **Snagit 12** and **Screenpresso** and am on the fence about which one I should get.

**I certainly like the price point better for Screenpresso (currently $23.88 for SP vs $49.95 for Snagit)**, but the free trial for Screenpresso has certain features locked down so really I am not sure what will give me the best solution for the work I do compared, with the full functionality vs the limited in the trial versions between the two.

Basically, the main features I found in Snagit that I find most useful, and would like to know if available in Screenpresso Pro, are the following:

- Shell integration (I can highlight a series of many images, and use the right click menu to convert the images in any number of ways without opening the whole application, size reduction, effects, file format, etc...)
- Library option with image history, automatic saves, tagging, categorization etc... If you have used both Snagit and Screenpresso Pro, can you provide a comparison of the feature set for libraries (if there is one to compare, not pros and cons, but functionality and workflow comparison)?
- Automatic Versioning - As soon as you make a change to an image or video in Snagit you can see in the workspace below a copy of the original is temporarily made until you finalize the end result under the same name as the original file.  During that time you can easily switch between the working version and the original on the same screen via the workspace area at the bottom.
- Stamp options - I didn't have 3rd party stamp packs until I purchased them recently, but does Screenpresso allow for importing the same packs as SnagIt (SuperStamps 4.0, for example)?

For now, these are the features I use most often, and would need Screenpresso to have similar functionality to sway my purchase decision. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used '**Screenpresso**' personally (only studied its reviews) but I am using **Snagit** from couple of years **(since version 9)** and found it to be one of the best tool available for image capturing, sharing, editing, recording etc. When it comes to creating screen shots for Bugs and images for HelpGuides, UserGuides and Tutorials etc. I personally found Snagit lacking nowhere, though the price of Snagit is double than that of Screenpresso, but I never regretted that why I am not using lower price tool. Other than Snagit I have used
 - PicPick
 - Greenshot
 - DuckCapture

http://beebom.com/2015/06/snipping-tool-alternatives

https://www.cloudswave.com/creative-tools/s/screenpresso/compare/snagit/

But in a single line from my side, Snagit is the best tool which suffice a tester needs. So, if price is not an issue and you think you will be able to get ROI (Return Over Investment) then without second thought you should go for Snagit. Else, as an alternative, you can contact 'Screenpresso' sales team, to provide a Pro version trial license key for 1 week (lets say), so that you can evaluate that too (many a times they provide it, as I have tried this with some automation tools so that I can review all features before making a final decision).

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I just went ahead and purchased SnagIt. I am familiar with it, it's quick and does everything I need. I just didn't want to spend $50, but it's worth it for the time I save. It pays for itself in no time at all just in hours saved using other tools, or multiple tools to accomplish the same tasks.